# Django serializing json

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-serializer

I'm building an API using django and I have come across a problem.
I have a UserDetail model that has a foreing key to a User model.

```py
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="", blank=True)
```

I want to serialize the information of User and the information of UserDetails in one json and this is what I'm currently doing:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')


class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserDetail
        fields = ('user', 'about',)
```

Right now I obtain this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "username": "julia",
        "first_name": "antonia",
        "last_name": "uri",
        "email": "as¡¡test@test.test"
    },
    "about": ""
}
```

But I want to obtain the information of UserDetail from User, not the other way around (like I'm currently doing) so that I get the information like this:

```
{
    "username": "julia",
        "first_name": "antonia",
        "last_name": "uri",
        "email": "test@test.test",
    "details": {
        "about": ""
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

**Edit**
Here is my view:

```py
#user = User.objects.select_related('userdetail').get(username=username)
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        userDetail = UserDetail.objects.get(user=user)

        if request.method == 'GET':
            serializer = DetailSerializer(userDetail)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Please add your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```py
class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetail
        fields = ('about',)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    details = DetailSerializer(many=False, source="userdetail")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'details')
```

`source=userdetail` is how you access `userdetail` from User model instance